# How to set gravity in the center box2d javascript

Tags: javascript, box2d, box2dweb

I need to set the gravity in a box2d world right in the center of the canvas. This means that objects will fall in the center of the canvas.

The box2d framework is the javascript framework.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gravity is not a location, it's a direction. To do what you want, you can set gravity to zero and apply a small force to all bodies every timestep, toward the location you want them to move to.